# Can I use my "local" public key to log into ssh from one server to another (vServer) and how (with PHP)?

Tags: php, ssh

Since I am quite new to this I think i just missunderstand something but I can't find any working solution so far online.
My setup is the following:
I have my local Computer I work on, a shared server with SSH functionality (at Hetzner) and a cloud vServer (also at hetzner).

I use the bitvise ssh client to connect to my vServer by using a public key I generated with this tool at my Computer. This works as expected.

Now I want to use the same method (and same key) to connect my shared Server with my vserver - this doesn't work.

Therefor I use the `ssh2_connect` method of PHP. Here is the code I use for that (it's a comment from php.net at the ssh2_connect function, but reduced):

```
$ssh_host = '[vServer_ip]';
// SSH Port
$ssh_port = 22;
// SSH Server Fingerprint
$ssh_server_fp = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
// SSH Username
$ssh_auth_user = '[vServer_username]';
// SSH Public Key File
$ssh_auth_pub = '/usr/www/users/[my_username]/.ssh/profile1.pub';
// SSH Key File
$ssh_auth_priv = '/usr/www/users/[my_username]/.ssh/profile1';
// SSH Key Passphrase (null == no passphrase)
$ssh_auth_pass = '[passphrase_from_my_public_key]';

function connect($ssh_host, $ssh_port, $ssh_server_fp, $ssh_auth_user, $ssh_auth_pub, $ssh_auth_priv, $ssh_auth_pass) {
    if (!($connection = ssh2_connect($ssh_host, $ssh_port))) {
        throw new Exception('Cannot connect to server');
    }
    $fingerprint = ssh2_fingerprint($connection, SSH2_FINGERPRINT_MD5 | SSH2_FINGERPRINT_HEX);
    if (strcmp($ssh_server_fp, $fingerprint) !== 0) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to verify server identity!');
    }
    if (!ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, $ssh_auth_user, $ssh_auth_pub, $ssh_auth_priv, $ssh_auth_pass)) {
        throw new Exception('Autentication rejected by server');
    }
    return $connection;
}

$connection = connect($ssh_host, $ssh_port, $connection, $ssh_server_fp, $ssh_auth_user, $ssh_auth_pub, $ssh_auth_priv, $ssh_auth_pass);
var_dump($connection);
```

What I receive is the error "**Uncaught Exception: Unable to verify server identity!**"

I am missing the content of the `$ssh_server_fp` variable since I don't know what to put there. The `profile1.pub` is the public key I used on my local computer and `profile1` the private key for it.

The pulic key was generated with `ecdsa-sha2-nistp521` encryption and exported via open ssh method. So the public keys content starts with `ecdsa-sha2-nistp521` and the private key with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it by doing 2 things.

1. I removed the fingerprint check for testing reasons because the used method with `strcmp` was outdated. (Gonna try to add some different fingerprint check later)
2. I did a stupid mistake and passed the `$connection` variable to the function call `connect()` resulting in a wrong passing order of the variables.

So, yeah it did work like it intended and the working code looks like this:

```
$ssh_host = '[vServer_ip]';
// SSH Port
$ssh_port = 22;
// SSH Server Fingerprint
$ssh_server_fp = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
// SSH Username
$ssh_auth_user = '[vServer_username]';
// SSH Public Key File
$ssh_auth_pub = '/usr/www/users/[my_username]/.ssh/profile1.pub';
// SSH Key File
$ssh_auth_priv = '/usr/www/users/[my_username]/.ssh/profile1';
// SSH Key Passphrase (null == no passphrase)
$ssh_auth_pass = '[passphrase_from_my_public_key]';

function connect($ssh_host, $ssh_port, $ssh_auth_user, $ssh_auth_pub, $ssh_auth_priv, $ssh_auth_pass) {
    if (!($connection = ssh2_connect($ssh_host, $ssh_port))) {
        throw new Exception('Cannot connect to server');
    }
    if (!ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, $ssh_auth_user, $ssh_auth_pub, $ssh_auth_priv, $ssh_auth_pass)) {
        throw new Exception('Autentication rejected by server');
    }
    return $connection;
}

$connection = connect($ssh_host, $ssh_port, $ssh_auth_user, $ssh_auth_pub, $ssh_auth_priv, $ssh_auth_pass);
var_dump($connection);
```